# OnPress Event targeting a Search button triggers Submit button for entire page

Tags: javascript, php, dom-events

I have the following form as part of a registration process:

```
<form class="form1" id="register_form1" method="POST" action="<?php echo $register_url; ?>" name="register_form1">

<!-- other parts of the form that are not relevant to this question -->             
<!-- text input area to conduct a search -->
 <span style="text-align: left; width: 100%;margin-left:40px;">Select a primary recruiter</span>
 <div class="ansDiv">
 <table style="float: left;">
   <tr>
   <td>
   <input type="text" id="primary_recruiter" name="primary_recruiter" value="" onkeypress="searchKeyPress(event);"> 
   </td>

   <td>
   <input type="button" id="buttonSearch" value="" class="button_search" name="seachprimary" onclick="javascript: searchRecruiter();">
   </td>

   <td>
   <a class="highlight" href="../images/PrimaryRecruiter.gif" style="float: right; padding-right: 655px;">
   <img src="../images/Q-btn.png">
   </a></td>                    

   <td>
   <input type="hidden" id="primary_recruiter_id" name="primary_recruiter_id" value="">
   </td></tr>
</table>            

<!-- last part of the form that is not relevant to this question -->

<!-- Submit button for the page itself. -->
<p align="center">
  <input type="submit" class="button_submit" name="register1_submit" value="" />
</p>
</form>
```

And here's the JavaScript I have setup to implement a button press on <kbd>Enter</kbd>:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

 function searchRecruiter(){
 var temp = $("#primary_recruiter").val();
    $.ajax({
        type : 'GET',
        url : 'searchrecruiter.php',
        data: "name="+temp,
        success : function(data){
         $("#displayrecruiterlist").html(data);
        }//end function(data) call
  });//end $.ajax call
 }//end searchRecruiter

//other java scripts
</script>


<!-- Press enter to search... -->    
  <script type="text/javascript">
    function searchKeyPress(e){

        // look for window.event in case event isn't passed in
        if (typeof e == 'undefined' && window.event) { e = window.event; }
        if (e.keyCode == 13){
            document.getElementById('buttonSearch').click();
        }               
    }
</script>
```

When I press enter on the text input box, I do end up on `document.getElementByID('buttonSearch').click();` so that works. But it then the
page responds as if I had clicked submit, which has no id attribute.

When I click on the search button, it works as expected.  What am I doing wrong?  I thought I was sending a click to the that Search button,
but that is not the response I'm having.

Things to keep in mind: I'm new to web development (PHP, JavaScript, etc.) and am learning on the job.
Please let me know if I need anything else I need to provide.

Comment: At least you could clean up your code from extra blank lines... In `searchKeyPress` you have to cancel original hit of ENTER.

Comment: That was the other caveat, I did not write this code originally.  How do I cancel the original hit of enter? Would adding **return false;** _after_ the .click() call do the trick?

:::attempting now:::

Comment: Attempt failed.  The reason I know this is that alerts for the empty fields are fired off when I press enter, but when I click the button directly, it works like normal.

Comment: Tis true I posted.  However, this is my first post on here, so that's why it looks so goofy.

Comment: You just could have more answers, if the code was more easy to read.

Comment: I see... Prepare the code in text editor, and paste it again. I drew back my earlier comment, since there was an error. Canceling events is a cross-browser issue. In IE you need this: `event.cancelBubble=true;event.returnValue=false;return false;`. Check documentation of the other browsers for event canceling.

Comment: I don't have enough rep to chat, so I'll say I used bluefish and then used it's indentation function when I initially posted.  I'll just use notepad in the future.  #lessonlearned

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pressing enter on a text input field will submit the parent form. Because the search field/button are actually performing their own function (pulling data with an AJAX call), they probably shouldn't be inside of the form at all. I would recommend pulling those items out and putting them outside of the form tag. That would solve your issue.

The other option would be to return false in the onkeypress event.

FYI, onclick="" is javascript syntax, so the javascript: at the beginning is implied and unnecessary.

Comment: Thanks for the FYI, I will get that out.

I added return false; after the .click() call, but had the same effect as before.  And it had the same effect when I put it at the end of the function.

I also tried setting it into its own form, but that failed as well.

Comment: That is how the customer wants the page to function.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "that is how the customer wants the page to function." Are you saying that they want the search text as part of the form submission? I was suggesting that you pull input field and button out of the form and put it outside the form, but not inside *another* form... just by itself (unless of course you do need the search text to be part of the form submission). Pressing enter inside of an input field will submit the form that it's part of, so by having not having it in a form at all, you wouldn't have this problem.

Comment: They want the user to be able to search for a recruiter and set that recruiter as a "primary recruiter" for their profile, and have the primary recruiter (or "I don't have a primary recruiter") to be saved to the profile during registration.  There's a search button right next to the text field, but they want to allow for people to also press enter and not have to click the search button.

I tried the form within a form on a lark.  I'm still new to this web development thing.

Comment: They want to pass the recruiter information as part of the form.  I didn't design the page, so I'm trying to figure this out from that angle in addition to being new at this.

Comment: @Waddler instead of onkeypress="searchKeyPress(event);", change it to onkeypress="return searchKeyPress(event);" You need to return the *result* of the searchKeyPress() in order for it to work. Add return false; underneath the .click() event.

Comment: So when I read your suggestion to take it out of the form, I see that resulting in those two being placed elsewhere on the page.

I am having trouble wrapping my mind around those being elsewhere in the HTML code, but in the same place on the page.  There is also a hidden input with that text field as well.

Comment: @waddler Just go back to how you have it in the original post above, but modify the two things I mentioned above: 1) change onkeypress="searchKeyPress(event);" to onkeypress="return searchKeyPress(event);" and 2) add return false; underneath document.getElementById('buttonSearch').click(); That will keep the input field within the form and prevent the enter button from submitting the parent form.

Comment: Thank you Kory.  That got the results I needed.  You are awesome.

Comment: The arrow is showing as green for me now. Is there a delay of any sort  from the site's end?